# Is it possible to convert OutStream to a string?

Tags: java, parsing, command-line, command-line-arguments, picocli

I have a method that uses DOM parsing to build an XML file and it takes an **OutputStream** as an argument. I'm trying to run the program from the command line, but the command line option only accepts strings.

I can run it by inputting *System.out* as an argument and running the the program, but that's it.

Here's a snippet of code:

```
public class WriteSourceTranslatedToTXML extends GetSourceSentences {

    public static String makeTranslated(OutputStream output, String out) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException, URISyntaxException {

        System.out.println("---creating XML file---");
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.setRootElement(new Element("txml"));

        // Built XML here and inserted sentences
        xmlOutputter.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
        xmlOutputter.output(doc, output);

        // Write to file
        XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter();
        String xml = xout.outputString(doc.getRootElement().getContent());

        try(FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =
               new FileOutputStream(out)) {
                   xmlOutputter.output(doc, fileOutputStream);
```

And here is the code for the command line:

```
@Command(name = "fileCli", description = "Performs file manipulation operations", mixinStandardHelpOptions = true, version = "File Client 1.0")

public class TranslateTXML implements Callable<String> {

    @Option(names = "-o", description = "output path")
    private String output;
    if (output != null) {
        WriteSourceTranslatedToTXML.makeTranslated(output); // Red line under output
        System.out.println("translated made");
        System.out.println("------");
        System.out.println("File \"translated.txml\" has been outputted to designated path");
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The call `makeTranslated(output)` with `output` being a `String` doesn't match the signature of the method, which is `makeTranslated(OutputStream output, String out)`.  It's not clear what your intent is.

Comment: I was just trying to see off I could get it to work with 2 args. Essentially what my program does is that it reads xml data from an xml file, calls an API for another set of data, builds a new xml file and inputs the data to the new xml file.

Comment: The outputStream method is responsible for writing the entire xml file and setting the destination of where on the drive the file should go. Perhaps I can do this: call my makeTranslated() method to create all the xml data > create another method " String myMethod(String filePath)" that will retrieve the data and return the file path so as to prevent the command line from retrieving any outputStream data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different method by which Java builds the XML file.

The new method call does not require an OutputStream argument, but simply a string, which I set as the filepath.

```
public static void createXml(String directory) throws IOException, TransformerException, ParserConfigurationException {

    BufferedReader sourceReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(db));

    .
    .

    // Use DocumentBuilder and construct the XML file using NodeList Collection
    .
    .

    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

    // Write to console or file
    StreamResult console = new StreamResult(System.out);
    StreamResult file = new StreamResult(new File(directory));
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

    // For pretty print
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

    // Write data
    transformer.transform(source, console);
    transformer.transform(source, file);
    sourceReader.close();
```

So by using DOM parser, Transformer, and StreamResult, I can build the .xml file and store it in a Stream with StreamResult (which requires a String parameter for output).
Voilà!